# Delphi Android App scaling

Tags: android, delphi, screen

I want to code an App in Delphi. but i have a little Problem.
My App needs to fit on any device screen. But on some devices which have a bigger/smaller screen it look weird.
How can i do that it automatically scales up?

Comment: set property Align to alClient of your component that you want to scale

Comment: There is no simple answer to the question. Put a TScaledLayout on the form and all your other controls on that. But then you get really tiny text on very small screens. The practical solution is to use a TScollLayout and keep the font 1 size and let the user scroll the view-port. None of this is easy to implement in code, however